# What is that painting in Glider 4.0

Tags: macos, glider

The Glider 4.0 game for the mac has a fairly iconic painting of a woman with... a Z symbol on her forehead? And on her... snowshoe?

(It can be seen several times in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8_ypI_C7nM) including in the last room.)

Is the painting a reference to some other artwork? Does it come from somewhere? What is the thing she appears to be holding? Has it appeared in any non-Glider games?

Comment: Not sure this helps... but there are other "OZ" related objects around her.

Comment: Could the downvoters please explain their reasonings? New users don't always know the site guidelines, and downvoting without explaining doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @Thunderforge Downvoting isn't for the poster.  You should know that by now.

Comment: @Frank Just recently, we had a blog post [about how Stack Overflow/Exchange isn’t very welcoming](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/). Unexplained downvotes for first time posters are one manifestation of that problem, and is likely to drive new users away. Why would explaining downvotes to teach new users about site guidelines be a bad thing?

Comment: @Thunderforge There's more to being welcoming than explaining voting.  And doing so is **optional**, and always has been.  Where's your proof that it's likely to drive new users away?  At what point does welcoming new users trump maintaining quality standards?  Either way, none of this should be in the comments here.  If you don't like people downvoting without commenting, take it up on Meta.

Comment: I am not a super new stack-exchanger, but I admit that just makes me more confused by the initial down-votes, because I thought I kinda-sorta knew how these stack exchanges were supposed to work. Was the question poorly worded? Was it inappropriate to link to a video containing the art rather than the art itself? Are old Mac games out of scope? Is asking about references for background art out of scope? I find the answer interesting now that I've learned what it is. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the Internet Archive's [Glider emulator](https://archive.org/details/GLIDER) I was able to re-discover that the default leaderboard topper for Glider 4.0 was "Ozma of Oz." The [Book cover for Ozma of Oz on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozma_of_Oz) matches the pixel art on the walls in Glider.